# Zend Routing -- Grabbing Variables from URL with Ampersands and not Slashes - Tapjoy

Tags: php, zend-framework, tapjoy

I'm currently creating attempting to integrate with the Tapjoy API with their callback URL request which comes in this form:

```
<callback_url>?snuid=<user_id>&currency=&mac_address=<mac_address>&display_multiplier=<display_multiplier>
```

However, using ZF1 -- 
the Zend_Controller_Router_Route seems to be dependent on the variable separation being delimited by slashes and not ampersands.

Here is my current Route code

```
>     $router->addRoute( 'api-tapjoy', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('api/tapjoy?snuid=:snuid&mac_address=:&mac_address&display_multiplier....etc.etc,
array('controller'=>'api', 'action' =>'tapjoy')));
```

Whenever I remove the ampersands and initial question mark  and replace them with slashes it works. How can I properly receive the HTTP Request whilst using ampersands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. It has nothing to do with ampersands and slashes, etc. but rather that my Route wasn't created properly.

I was thrown off by [this documentation on ZF1's website about routers:](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)

> The first parameter in the Zend_Controller_Router_Route constructor is
>   a route definition that will be matched to a URL. Route definitions
>   consist of static and dynamic parts separated by the slash ('/')
>   character. Static parts are just simple text: author. Dynamic parts,
>   called variables, are marked by prepending a colon to the variable
>   name: :username.